# DBI::dbWriteTable isn't writing a SQLite table to disk

Tags: r, rsqlite

I'm just getting started with using `DBI` to access (local) SQLite databases, and I seem to be having basic problems reading and writing to disk.  Here's a reprex:

```r
library(DBI)

con = dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = 'test.db')
dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = "Tbl_test", value = mtcars)
dbListTables(conn = con)
#> [1] "Tbl_test"
dbDisconnect(con)

con = dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = 'test.db')
dbListTables(conn = con)
#> character(0)
dbDisconnect(con)

sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] DBI_1.1.0
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6    digest_0.6.25   magrittr_1.5    evaluate_0.14  
#>  [5] RSQLite_2.2.0   highr_0.8       rlang_0.4.6     stringi_1.4.6  
#>  [9] blob_1.2.1      vctrs_0.3.1     rmarkdown_2.1   tools_4.0.0    
#> [13] stringr_1.4.0   bit64_0.9-7     bit_1.1-15.2    xfun_0.13      
#> [17] yaml_2.2.1      compiler_4.0.0  pkgconfig_2.0.3 memoise_1.1.0  
#> [21] htmltools_0.4.0 knitr_1.28
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The first bit appears to correctly add a new table using the data from `mtcars`.  But nothing is written to disk in the working directory (or anywhere else, based on a Finder search).  The second bit doesn't throw an error that it can't find the database file; it just quietly fails to find any tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the  `dbname` parameter when you connect to the DB.
If you don't, the DB will be created in memory and disappear as you disconnect.
`path` doesn't belong to [SQLlite arguments](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RSQLite/versions/2.2.0/topics/SQLite) and isn't taken into account : the DB is created in your working directory.

```
library(DBI)

con = dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),dbname = 'test.db', path = "#?*_~")
dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = "Tbl_test", value = mtcars)
dbListTables(conn = con)
#> [1] "Tbl_test"
dbDisconnect(con)

dir(".")
#>[1] "test.db"  

con = dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = 'test.db')
dbListTables(conn = con)
#> [1] "Tbl_test"
dbDisconnect(con)
```